# How to create collections dynamically and insert json file's data in to each of them

Tags: python, pymongo

On ref SO suggestions , I tried inserting a bunch of Json files data to single collection as :

```
import json
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb+srv://********:*******@cluster0-kb3os.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
db = client['mydb']
test = db['test']
```

Then I have the json files as a.json,b.json,....,z.json , to insert all these to a single collection, I did this way as:

```
file_names = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
json_file_names=[x + '.json' for x in file_names]

for file_name in json_file_names:
    with open(file_name,encoding="utf8") as f:
        file_data = json.load(f)
        for word in file_data:
            word_obj = file_data[word]
            test.insert_one(word_obj)
```

When querying the results which is referring to particular letter record,I guess it is good to have the separate collection which might increase performance too instead of searching whole collection.

I have been looking on how to create collections dynamically such that each collection say `a_col` has `a.json` data inserted,`b_col` has `b.json`, ........

Is there a way to create as this ? , any guiding links or snippets as answer would be much helpful , TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your for loop after reading each files change collection name accoeding to your file name. like `test = db[filename]` it will create a new collection everytime before inserting data.

Comment: Thanks a ton mate,for anyone's ref,  this line after loading file to file_data does the work:   `test=db[file_name]`